# Replace My Wishlist Text with Icon

Tags: magento2, toplinks, magento2.4, icon

I want to know how to replace the "My Wish List" text in toplinks with an icon. I don't want an Icon with pseudo code like "::before". Adding a `<i> </i>`- tag in the code should be the solution.

The text of My Wish List we can edit in "getLabel()" function of  "Link.php" in module-wishlist. But I don't want any text. Only the Icon should be in storefront visible. If I set the return value to an empty string in getLabel() function then in mobile view it is not visible.

Where I can do that?
I think we need to create an own module and overwrite the files. But which file and what exactly?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove label and add icon from the template file.
For that you have to override `vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/link.phtml` file in your theme and replace label code with icon code.

Override file path should be like this:

```
app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Wishlist/templates/link.phtml
```

Code of label looks like:

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel()) ?>
```

You can replace it with:

```
<i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
```

Comment: You are my man! Thank you :)